# query results differ in APM Traces vs Metrics/Dashboard/Notebook etc

Tags: datadog

I found some interesting metrics in APM Traces, and I clicked on "export" to add them to my Notebook. However on the Dashboard, I see no data on my graph even after adjusting the time range.
I also noticed that the 2 pages have slightly different UI to build the query, but I don't know how to adjust my query in APM Traces to show up on other places.

UI in APM traces
[image]

UI in Metrics etc.
[image]

How do I add the exact graph that I saw on APM Traces to Metrics etc, and why do the 2 pages have slightly different UI (under the search bar)?

I am unable to find documentation explaining the difference between the 2 either.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting in case anyone's experiencing something similar:

In my case it was retention filters. The Export dropdown has a warning at the bottom, "APM queries in monitors, dashboards and notebooks are based on spans indexed by [custom retention filters](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_pipeline/trace_retention/#retention-filters) only", and filters were set to retain `status:error`.

The APM results populating the source graph had all as `status:ok`, so the graph was empty after export since those aren't retained.